# Using of the slice command in the loadash

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, numbers, shared-libraries

I Need to write a function that thats getting an array and a number, if the number is positive then the function will put it inside his place, which means for the array 1,2,3,4,5 the number 2 will be at the 2nd spot.
but if the number is negative (for example -2) it will be counted from the end of the array (-2 will be presented instead of 3)

currently my code is this:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const pleasework = (word,value) => {
_.slice(word, [start=0], [end=value.length]) }
console.log(pleasework((5),[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

would love your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem correct, You might be able to achieve it even without using `lodash`. You can use Node.js builtin method `splice`.

you can read about [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) here.

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
const pleaseWork = (word, value) => { 
 let newArray = [...a];
 newArray.splice(value, 0, word);
 return newArray;
}
```

Splice function takes three paramters

- 1st The positioned index where you want to insert the item.
- 2nd How many elements you would like to remove from array (optional)
- 3rd Which value you would like to insert.

If the first element is a negative number it would insert it from the end.

I hope it helps.
The `splice` method changes the content of original array that is why I have created a new array.